# php/mysql SERF urls

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have looked and look and I cannot get this working. I have tried to do it with .htaccess and other tries but nothing is working.

I am trying to get from new-machinery.php?Item=100 to new-machinery/Item-Name

This what I have for my product pages.

```
 <?php

$LimitAmt = $Amt + 1;
$Limit = "LIMIT $LimitAmt";
$NextPage = $Page + 1;
$PrevPage = $Page - 1;


$SQLCat = "";
if (strlen($Cat) > 1)
{
$SQLCat = "AND (`Category` LIKE '$Cat;%' OR `Category` LIKE '%;$Cat' OR `Category` LIKE '$Cat')";   
}


$SQL_GetEquipment = "SELECT * FROM `new_equip` WHERE `condition`='New' $SQLCat $Limit";
$R_GetEquipment = mysql_query($SQL_GetEquipment, $Link);

$name = mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
$model = mysql_result($result,$i,"model");
$manu = mysql_result($result,$i,"manu");
$desc = mysql_result($result,$i,"desc");
$imagename = mysql_result($result,$i,"image");*/

$eid = $row['id'];
$itemname = $row['itemname'];
$model = $row['model'];
$manufactuer = $row['manufactuer'];
$desc = $row['desc'];
$imagename = $row['image'];


if (!file_exists("UImages/" . $imagename) || strlen($imagename) < 5)
{
$imagename = "NoImage.jpg";
}
?>
```

And to display the products url I have

```
<a itemprop="url" href="new-product.php?Item=<?php echo $itemname; ?>"><span itemprop="name"><?php echo $itemname; ?></span></a>
```

Like I said, I have looked and tried everything I could find but I keep getting a 404 page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What did you try with .htaccess? What does the code you're showing have to do with rewrites?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: I wasn't sure if you needed to see my code to see if I was doing something wrong.

Comment: What you did with the `.htaccess` would be useful and what errors/issues specifically you encountered.

Comment: Also, everything I read, has it going like /product/ProductID/ I need it to be product/ProductName/. I tried following this https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: Try `href="new-product/<?php echo $itemname; ?>">` then in htaccess send `^newproduct/(.*)` to `new-product.php?Item=$1` make sure you encode that `$itemname` appropriately though. Also update your driver to `PDO` or `mysqli` and use prepared statements.

Comment: I tried converting to mysqli and couldn't grasp it. Had me confused. Will try your suggestion. Thank You

Comment: I added RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^new-product/(.*) new-product.php?Item=$1and the url I am getting is new-product.php?Item=Item Name, but it is blank, not pulling the

Comment: What is the `-`? Did you url encode the `$itemname`? Also did you change the `href` on your page?

Comment: By doing that I get the URL - new-product.php?Item=Item+Name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91682/discussion-between-chris85-and-webbieworks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change your links to the format you want. Something like

```
href="new-product/<?php echo $itemname; ?>">
```

In your `.htaccess` you want something like.

```
RewriteRule ^new-product/(.*) new-product.php?Item=$1
```

The `^` is the start of the URL.
The `()` captures the values inside it.
The `.` is an character and the `*` is zero or more occurrences of any character. So bascially `.*` is equal to `anything`.
The `$1` is the value from the first capture group. If you have 2 capture groups they are in order of appearance.

So this `new-product/(.*)` is the url on the back end the `RewriteRule` tells apache to send the request to PHP as `new-product.php?Item=$1`.

So in your PHP you're going to need to change your call so it checks for the name rather than the ID.

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Item']); 
$SQL_GetEquipment = "SELECT * FROM `new_equip` WHERE `itemname`='$name' LIMIT 1;"; 
$R_GetEquipment = mysql_query($SQL_GetEquipment, $Link); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($R_GetEquipment);
```

The fetched data doesn't need to be escaped. The escaping is so your SQL statement can't be manipulated by inserting additional characters.

The preferred approach for this is using paramaterized queries unfortunately `mysql_` functions don't support that. I'd recommend you update to `PDO` or `mysqli_` so you can take advantage of these.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1:_Prepared_Statements_.28Parameterized_Queries.29
http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php
[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

If other people had the older format you'll need to make a rewrite controller. The htaccess will need to send to a PHP page that has DB access so it can pull the name from the ID, then resend it... or do a conditional check on your page and if the parameter is an integer check it by id.

Comment: You have help above and beyond. I appreciate all your help and knowledge on this.